# Find a harmonic function in the region $S$ satisfying boundary conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am not making much progress on this one folks. Any help would be much appreciated...

$\\$

***The lines $ \ y=x \ $ and $ \ x=1 \ $ divide the plane into four wedges. Let $S$ be the one which is above $ \ y=x \ $ and to the left of $ \ x=1 $. Find a function $\phi(x,y)$ which is harmonic in $S$ and satisfies $ \ \phi=2 \ $ on the vertical part of the boundary of $S$ and $ \ \phi=-8 \ $ on the slanted part of the boundary of $S$.***

$\\$

If I am not mistaken, we cannot use the form $ \ A \ Arg(z) \ + \ B \ $ due to the fact that the non-positive axis lies inside the region of interest. But I am not sure where to go from there. I am also a little confused about what adjustment (if any) is needed since the lines do not intersect at the origin (as opposed to all the wedge examples I have seen before this).

Comment: You can translate the function:
$$A \,Arg(z-(1,1)) + B$$ Now adjust $A $ and $B$.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for the help. I`m still a bit confused though (sorry, I`m very new to complex analysis). What does this adjustment look like in terms of the solution? For instance, if the line $\ x=1 \  $was $ \ x=0 \ $ instead (everything else unchanged), am I correct in saying that the boundary condition equations would be $\ A \ (\pi/2) \ + \ B = 2 \  $ and $\ A \ (5\pi/4) \ + \ B = -8 \ $?

Comment: Which gives the resulting solution of $\ \phi(z) = 26/3 - (40/3\pi)arg_0(z). \ $ What does the adjustment look like?